# How can the version of a Team Foundation Server be determined programmatically?

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I'm working on a tool that works on both TFS2010 and TFS11. However, there are some features that are specific to TFS11, so I'd like to disable them when connecting to a server running TFS2010.

Is there any way to retrieve the version of the Team Foundation Server via the TFS API? I haven't found anything in the object model available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146.aspx#ServerObjectModel).

I found this [blog post](http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/programmatically-detect-your-team-foundation-server-version/), which is interesting, but isn't a reasonable solution, since it requires using the TFS11 object model and it's entirely possible to connect to a TFS11 server using the TFS2010 object model.