# Get the Installed TFS Server version from TFS API (Is it 2010 or 2012?)

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I have a WCF service that calls both TFS 2010 and 2012 instances. I'm looking for a way to distinguish between 2010 and 2012 in the API, but there doesn't seem to be a GetServerVersion() or similar API.

The reason is that there were slight changes in the way that 2010 and 2012 handle work item links:

- Work Item Links in 2010: `http://TFSUri/web/wi.aspx?id=WorkItemID`
- Work Item Links in 2012: 
  `http://TFSUri/TFSProject/_workitems/edit/WorkItemID`

Worst case I can make people select their version, but I'd really prefer to automatically distinguish 2010 vs. 2012 if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IBuildServer` interface from Build.Client to get the version of the server.

```
TeamFoundationServer tfs = new TeamFoundationServer(@"http://yourtfs:8080/tfs");
IBuildServer tfsb = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();
Console.WriteLine(tfsb.BuildServerVersion); //v3 for 2010 and v4 for 2012
```

Answer (score 3):

Providing I understand your use-case the alternative, and arguably better way than defining a URL pattern for a given TFS version, is to use the [`TswaClientHyperlinkService`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff737417.aspx) to generate your URLs. You can use this API class to generate a URL for a given work item Id for example, through the [`GetWorkItemEditorUrl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff736178.aspx) method; e.g. using the v11 client dlls :

```cs
var collection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(
                     new Uri("http://<tfsuri>/tfs/<collection>/"));

var hyperlinkService = collection.GetService<TswaClientHyperlinkService>();
var link = hyperlinkService.GetWorkItemEditorUrl(<workitemid>);

// against TFS 2012:
// var link: 
//  http://<tfsuri>/tfs/web/wi.aspx?pcguid=<guid>&id=<workitemid>
// redirects to 
//  http://<tfsuri>/tfs/<collection>/<project>/_workitems#_a=edit&id=<workitemid>
```

I haven't got a TFS 2010 instance to test this against, but fingers crossed this would be transparent across calls to different versions.

---

All that said, this question has been [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234253/how-can-the-version-of-a-team-foundation-server-be-determined-programmatically). But the method in the link of the accepted answer derives different versions by identifying  functionality introduced at each release. This is applicable to differentiating 2005, 2008 and 2010. I don't know if the same approach can be used to differentiate 2010 and 2012 (or if a more palatable API method now exists).

Comment: Thanks! I started using this for hyperlinks and was able to make it work for both 2010 and 2012.